# Tela de cadastro pulando campo com "Enter"

Tags: android

Fiz uma tela de cadastro, mas quando o usuário dá enter no teclado ela pula uma linha. Tem como bloquear isto ?
Segue os prints para melhor entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coloque o atributo abaixo no `EditText` em questão

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

**EDIT**

Como dito, o `android:singleLine` foi descontinuado a partir da API 3. Você terá que usar o `android:maxLines`. No seu caso, `android:maxLines="1"`.

O singleLine foi descontinuado por questões de performance, porém não será removido por conta de alguns efeitos que o `maxLines` não consegue fazer.

Por exemplo, o código abaixo um texto scrollable horizontal em uma linha, caso o texto seja selecionado.

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

Esse código não

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080073/alternative-of-singleline-attribute-deprecated-textinputedittext) para a fonte.

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Usa `android:maxLines="1"` o `android:singleLine` tornou-se obsoleto recentemente

Comment: ele foi depreciado na API 3, se não me engano. Mas ainda é usual para alguns efeitos que não se consegue com o maxLines ou minLines.